# How to create pagination in windows 8 METRO (C# / XAML) Application?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

i want to create a pagination / paging for my listbox.

i have a list box , there will be for about 200 items showing up in my listbox ,

so i want to perform pagination on my list box and show 15  items per page , and when user presses next button it will be going to next page and when user presses previous button it will be going to previous page .

Please let me know , How can i implement this my application.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you are looking for:

Discussion:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/winappswithcsharp/thread/9d3cadd3-dc95-4219-9f90-e1aae6ad25c8

DataFetchSize method
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.datafetchsize.aspx

LoadMoreItemsAsync method:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.loadmoreitemsasync.aspx

IncrementalLoadingTrigger and IncrementalLoadingThreshold  properties 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.incrementalloadingtrigger.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.incrementalloadingthreshold.aspx

You can see examples of using these here (though note that the sample was based on Windows 8 BUILD release and the apis have had some changes)
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/e71b7036-4fb7-4963-a65d-5bcb9fd8f664

and take a look at Hamid's BUILD session that discusses these here:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/APP-517T

Comment: thanks for the reply , i will go through it and in case of any doubts i will ask you , once again thanks for the reply.